# Script not running on system startup

Tags: shell

I am trying to run a script at every system startup. Here is the Script :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(sensible-browser http://localhost/example/user=$USER)
```

I put copied the script to `/etc/init.d/` changed the file permission to 755 and then ran the command `sudo update-rc.d scriptname.sh defaults`.

tried to run the script via `/etc/rc.local` too but no luck. Nothing Happens when the system boots up.
What else can I do ?

Comment: What operating system (output of `uname -sr`)?

Comment: Where do you look for the output of the `echo`?

Comment: If the script runs it opens up the web browser. and my OS is Linux 3.2.0-30-generic (UBUNTU)

Comment: It runs from the commandline, but not from `/etc/wherever`?

Comment: sorry i didnt get you can you please elaborate ?

Comment: When you say "If the script runs", how do you run it?

Comment: Thats the thing I thought that I had to run it just like other scripts who starts running on system boot for example like 'apache2' from /etc/init.d/

Comment: but since it depends on opening a web browser that is not possible as you explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually don't want to start a browser at system startup--you want to start it after you log in. For that your shell provides startup files (e.g. `$HOME/.profile` for Bourne heritage shells, or `$HOME/.login` for csh type shells). As an alternative, X11 programs can be started from `$HOME/.xinitrc` or `$HOME/.xsession`.

Maybe we can help if we knew what you were actually trying to achieve.

Comment: The script as you already figured it redirects to a Php file which logs in to a SMS gateway and send a SMS that $user has logged in the system.

Comment: This doesn't work with `/etc/init.d` scripts; they are not run upon login. You can try placing code in system-wide shell startup scripts, like `/etc/profile` (for Bourne Shells that read them). You could try watching who is logged in using the `w` or `who` commands and do your thing if that changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your default webbrowser requires X to run (e.g. firefox). When the rc.d scripts run, it's not necessarily that your script runs after X is started (or that you have permissions to open a window). If you want to have your browser pop up the page `http://localhost/example/user=$USER`, you're going to have to look into KDM or GDM or whatever display manager you have and have it run an external script after startup.

Comment: when I try to run the script from Startup Application Preference It runs perfectly. Might be the reason that you are giving. but i want this script to run for all the users using Startup Application Preference makes it limited to particular user only.